# Old updated in marker in Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, location, marker

I created an app with Google Maps. I've put a custom marker in my current position. It is created. But on the street when I move the marker is fixed but the blue dot moves.

Why not update the marker?

```
LocationManager locationManager;
private String provider;
Marker markerPosicion = null;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    cargarLocalizacion();
paintOthersMarkers();
...
}

private void cargarLocalizacion() {

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    if (location != null) {
      onLocationChanged(location);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 1, this);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    if(markerPosicion != null) {
        markerPosicion.remove();
    }

    LatLng point = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

    markerPosicion = mapa.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(point)
        .icon(R.drawable.icon)
        .title("location"));
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Updating user's location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18573351/updating-users-location)

Comment: mapa is GoogleMap variable?

Comment: it's not duplicate. My code is very similiar but my code not works

Comment: I think, you should refresh your map on location changed listener.

Comment: `OnLocationChanged()` to make `mapa.clear()`?